# Cannot modify files with SAMBA and CurlFTPfs

Tags: linux, debian, samba, file-permissions, curlftpfs

I have all my ftp accounts mounted via CurlFTPfs with allow-others option. All directories have --- --- rwx (0007) permission after ftp mount with umask=0770 . This way I can log as another user (than root) in shell with full access. However it is not possible to modify files via SAMBA. How to mount SAMBA share to have all permissions?
Here is my smb.conf

```
[global]
dos charset=UTF8
unix charset=UTF8
workgroup = PPHU
server string = Samba Fileshare running %v
security = user

unix password sync = no
log level = 1
log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
max log size = 50
socket options = TCP_NODELAY SO_RCVBUF=8192 SO_SNDBUF=8192
wins support = no
name resolve order  = host lmhost wins bcast

[ftp]
comment = FTP
path = /mnt/ftp
create mask = 777
directory mask = 777
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this directive to your mount command:

```
-o allow_other,uid=1000
```